# Insert HTML after certain paragraph of HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a HTML-string I'd like to render but append some HTML after the 2nd paragraph first.

```
function insertStuff() {
  //var string = "<div><p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p><p>paragraph 3</p></div>"; works
  var string = '<p><img src="http://example.com/my-cool-picture.png" alt="alt text"></p><p>2nd paragraph</p><p>3rd paragrpah</p>' // doesn't work
  var parsedHtml = $(string)
  parsedHtml.find("p:nth-child(2)").after("<p>My cool insert</p>")
  return parsedHtml.html()
}
```

This works for the HTML string above but the following one only return the `<img>` after invoking `parsedHtml.html()`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately the `.find()` method only works for child nodes, therefore you will have to wrap your string with a `<div>`, use `.find()` and append content accordingly, and then unwrap it thereafter.

Comment: This  might help http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/u6d5m8hn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are use `.html()` it will return html of first element.

You can wrap your content in a `div` like

```
var parsedHtml = $('<div />').html(string)
```

Then your code will work.

```js
function insertStuff() {
  var string = '<p><img src="http://example.com/my-cool-picture.png" alt="alt text"></p><p>2nd paragraph</p><p>3rd paragrpah</p>'
  var parsedHtml = $('<div />').html(string)
  parsedHtml.find("p:nth-child(2)").after("<p>My cool insert</p>")
  return parsedHtml.html()
}

alert(insertStuff())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function insertStuff() {
  var string = '<div><p><img src="http://example.com/my-cool-picture.png" alt="alt text"></p><p>2nd paragraph</p><p>3rd paragrpah</p></div>';
  var parsedHtml = $(string)
  parsedHtml.find("p:nth-child(2)").after("<p>My cool insert</p>")
  return parsedHtml.html()
}
```

You should put this string in a `div` as `parent`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `html` method as getter returns html content of the first element in the set. You should either wrap all the top-level elements in the set with another element and read it's html content or iterate through the set and concatenate each element's `outerHTML` property.

```
parsedHtml.map(function() { return this.outerHTML; }).get().join('');
```

If you want to get the `innerHTML` of all the elements in the set, replace `outerHTML` with `innerHTML`.

Comment: how can I return the content of all elements in the set? I don't want to wrap the content

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I think I'll go with wrapping it in a `<div`

Answer (score 0):

when you use find() with a selector it will search inside that selector (in child nodes) that why when you use string with div tag you are getting the desired result and when you delete div the problem occured

Comment: use this code   function insertStuff() {
                //var string = "<div><p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p><p>paragraph 3</p></div>"; works
                var string = '<div><p>test</p><p>2nd paragraph</p><p>3rd paragrpah</p></div>' // doesn't work
                var parsedHtml = $(string);
               
                parsedHtml.find("p:nth-child(2)").after("<p>My cool insert</p>")
               
               // return parsedHtml.html()
                return parsedHtml.html();
            }